# Read a large text file into Textview

Tags: android

I want to read large file from sdcard into text view.
I have idea but i don't know how to apply.

I think this things need to use:
Handler And
Thread

But i dont know how to apply.
Anybody give some example or Tutorial.

**Updated:**

```
Thread test=new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
    File sfile=new File(extras.getString("sfile"));
    try {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(sfile));
        String line1;
        while(null!=(line1=br.readLine()))
        {
            text.append(line1);
            text.append("\n");
        }
        subtitletv.setText(text.toString());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
        }
    };
    test.start();
```

This is my code.But it is better than previous code, 
but it is not able to read 2MB file.
How to slove this?
And How to set Progress?

Comment: Define *not able*. Do you get an error? If so, what?

Comment: After a min it shows force close. http://pastebin.com/evFjA0Pf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it. If the file is so large that it's going to take more than about 5 seconds to read, then it should probably just be an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

```
// first open the file and read it into a StringBuilder
String cardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(cardPath + "/filename.txt"));
StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    total.append(line);
}
r.close();

// then get the TextView and set its text
TextView txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_view_id);
txtView.setText(total.toString());
```

**EDIT**

You can only change UI elements in the UI thread. The [documentation on threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#Threads) has more details. When you try to do it from another thread, you get this (from your pastebin):

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 8517): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

I think the easiest solution is using [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), as I recommended before. You just put your work code in one function (`doInBackground()`) and your UI code in another (`onPostExecute()`), and `AsyncTask` makes sure they get called on the right threads and in order. The documentation I linked to has examples with loading bitmaps, which is just about the same thing as loading text.

Comment: Updated my question.Thanks but new problem.Not able to read Larger file than 2MB

Comment: @Cyboysa The error you're getting is not for the file size--it's for thread safety issues. When you use `Thread`, you have to manage thread safety manually. Try `AsyncTask` and see if that works.

Comment: Wow, that is fast oO Never thought that the StringBuilder in combination with the BufferedReader will have that impact on performance. Thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are accessing a View owned by the GUI thread from the thread that is reading your file:

```
subtitletv.setText(text.toString());
```

You need to read the file, then pass its contents to the main thread to be displayed.

```
//Create a handler on the UI Thread:
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

//Executed in a non-GUI thread:
public void updateView(){
    final String str = TheDataFromTheFile;
    mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
             subtitletv.setText(str);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UI can be updated by using this also:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {

       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new thread then using `openFileforInput` read all file data into StringBuffer.

Use `TextView.setText()` method to set data.