# Android TextView and EditText that can handle large quantities of text

Tags: android

**Wanted**

I'd like to have a TextView and EditText that can handle large quantities of text.

**Problem**

Loading a textfile with a rough size of 1mb is quick, but putting this content into a TextView or EditText is painfully slow. (Tested on a Nexus 5) Four-ish years ago Samsung phones also had a limit which could be overcome with this `android:maxLength="999999999"` in your layout file fin the TextView/EditText element. Not sure if this still works as I haven't needed it for a while, but it doesn't speedup anything.

**Question**

Does anyone know of any way to overcome this slowness? Or does anyone know a library that can do this natively?

I know you can display lots of text with a WebView and probably with a bit of javascript and hacking get an inputfield in a webview work as an EditText. But I would prefer a more native solution first.

**TextRecyclerView** maybe? So that anything outside of the visible field is recycled?

Comment: This is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579603/read-a-large-text-file-into-textview

Comment: @AnyssaK No its not, the problem is not reading the file, the problem is putting it in the textview. textView.setText(content);

Comment: Are you using an `AsyncTask`? Have you considered appending the text per line instead of setting it all at once?

Comment: (Hacky idea) break the text by line and store in a List<String>, use ListView/ArrayAdapter system to render the large dataset in pieces.

Comment: @Guardanis this was my initial idea, but it becomes kind of problematic with the EditText if I want to select parts of the text.

Comment: Crap, didn't think of that one...

Comment: I still think its doable, just a bit harder. This is why I'm wondering if anyone knows of any library that already does this. :)

Comment: You might want to try altering the layout params of your textview like match_parent which does not causes redraw for entire hierarchy.

Comment: Hi did you find anything about this, I didn't find a workaround. I was thinking about creating a edittext that would work with a dataadapter, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Thanks @Cruceo, You suggestion is Working for me :-)

Comment: how would I add content to an EditText using an adapter? does anyone have an example?